# Specify immediate offset with GCC Extended ASM

Tags: c, assembly, gcc, x86, inline-assembly

I am using GCC 10.3.0 and I have this source code:

```
__asm__ volatile
(
    "movl %%gs:%0, %%eax\n\t"
    : "=a"(some_output) 
    : "i"(immediate_value)
);
```

I want to make GCC translate this instruction into

```
movl %gs:immediate_value, %eax
```

but because I am using AT&T syntax and using immediate value I get additional '$':

```
movl %gs:$immediate_value, %eax
```

and this is an incorrect AT&T syntax.

I know tha I can use 'r' constraint instead of 'i', which will be ok, but I need to get exactly this opcode with immediate value.

The second solution is to rewrite asm code using Intel syntax and to pass `-masm=intel` to the compiler. But then I get errors with `htons` function: with optimization flag `-O3` GCC substitutes some AT&T asm code instead of direct call.

Please, advise me some solutions.

Comment: You're looking for https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#x86Operandmodifiers - `%c0` prints the constant without punctuation, even in AT&T mode.  This is probably a duplicate... looking now.

Comment: @PeterCordes, thank you. That is exactly what I nedded.

Comment: Also consider something like `asm volatile("movl %%gs:%0, %%eax" : "=a"(output) : "m"(*(char*)immediate));`